# Connecting to SQL Server with pyodbc over VPN

Tags: vpn, pyodbc

I have some code that establishes a connection to SQL server using `pyodbc`. However, soon the SQL server will only accept connections from a VPN. I need to therefore modify the connection to go via a VPN.

How can I achieve that pyodbc?

Comment: Your vpn needs to be transparent to the network

Answer (score 2):

The VPN connection will need to be established first, this isn't a problem that can be solved directly by `pyodbc`.